# Why last-child selector is not working in SCSS?

Tags: css, sass

I have two paragraph tags.

```
<p>This is the first line</p>
<p>This is the second line</p>
```

I want to change the color of the second

using scss.
This is what scss I'm writing.

```
p {
  color: blue;

  &:last-child {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Is my syntax wrong? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It definitely is the right way to do it. [Check here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_last-child) to verify. I am guessing you have a hidden or misplaced ```p``` tag somewhere that's affecting you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use `last-of-type`

```
 p {
    color: blue;   
    &:last-of-type {
      color: red;
    }
 }
```

The :last-of-type CSS pseudo-class represents the last element of its type among a group of sibling https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type

EDIT: just for proof of concept

```css
p {
  color: blue;
}
p:last-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>First</p>
<p>Second</p>
<div>Not a P</div>
<p>Third</p>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```html
p {
  color: blue;

  & + & {
    color: red;
  }
}
```